# How do i check a remote soap service from bash and check it has a specific string

Tags: xml, bash, curl, soap

I want to check a remote soap server, by sending it some xml and greping for a string? If it's successful i want to output an xml file so that i can use pingdom to check the uptime of the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the script i used to do this.  Add it to cron, run it every sixty seconds, output the result into a web root and use the http custom check in pingdom or other monitoring tool:

```
#!/bin/bash
# result file
file="/var/www/vhostwebroot/out.xml"

# remove the file if exists (from previous runs)    
if [ -e $file ];then
  rm $file
fi

# set start time
start=$(date +%s%3N)

# soap_text.xml is the soap call you want to post to the remote server
test=$(curl --silent -d @soap_test.xml -H "Content-Type: application/soap+xml" -H 'SOAPAction: ""' https://www.soap-server-to-check/service-endpoint | grep -o 'string you want to check for')

# set end time
end=$(date +%s%3N)

# calculate elapsed time
el=$(($end-$start))

# if the string exists, output an xml file
if [ "$test" = 'string you want to check for' ]
then

# output the appropriately formatted file for pingdom to check
echo "<pingdom_http_custom_check> 
      <status>OK</status> 
      <response_time>$el</response_time> 
      </pingdom_http_custom_check>" > $file
else
# if the check fails, output a failure doc
echo "<pingdom_http_custom_check> 
      <status>DOWN</status> 
      <response_time>$el</response_time> 
      </pingdom_http_custom_check>" > $file
fi
```

Comment: Initially i was using the bash variable $SECONDS to report the response time, but this was always outputting 1s because of the precision of the variable, so i ended up using time and bc to output the seconds and milliseconds.